# Attributes are an example of Decorator?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

The decorator pattern applies when there is a need to dynamically add responsibilities to a class, and when subclassing would be impossible due to the large number of subclasses that could result.

Given above definition I would think attributes is decorator. Or could it be considered Proxy or Adapter?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, .NET attributes are basically their way of implementing the decorator pattern.

Comment: I would say that .NET attributes decorates "things", but decorator pattern is a something else.

Comment: @Nilesh: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern, maybe I am being wrong here but I can't see the similarities to .NET attributes and decorator pattern.